# Python SpaCy Regex does not pick up the token that contains a word

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I am running below simple code to obtain all tokens that contains the word ( for example, words containing acompared, notcompared, thiscompared).

But, the spaCy regex does not return anything. The regular expression word fine on python re.

Could you let me know if this is an spaCy issue or how resolve the issue?

It returns [], empty list.

```
import plac
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher, Matcher
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span, Token
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = """
"Net income was $9.4 million acompared to the prior year of $2.7
million.",
"Revenue exceeded twelve billion dollars, with a loss of $1b. run",
"""

doc = nlp(text)

pattern = [{"LOWER": {"REGEX": "\b\wcompared\w\b"}}]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("item", None, pattern )
matches = matcher(doc)
print(matches)
print(matcher)
```

This code should return the location of "acompared" token.

Comment: i don't see this regex working fine for python re too,as you have `\wcompared\w` so it will try to match `word followed by compared followed by word (surrounded by  word boundaries )` which is not available in text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the above answers work on python `re`, SpaCy requires a specific type of pattern description format. The pattern should contain word "TEXT" instead. For example,

```
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "compared*"}}].
```

Answer (score 1):

#### RegEx 1

If we'd be looking for any word with `compared` in it, maybe this expression might work:

```
\b\w*(?:compared)\w*\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxOP2a/1/)

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"\b\w*(?:compared)\w*\b"

test_str = "some text you wish before then compared or anythingcompared or any_thing_01_compared_anything_after_that "

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

---

#### RegEx 2

If we might want to find strings with `compared` in it, my guess is that this expression in `s` mode,

```
^(?=.*\bacompared\b|\bthiscompared\b|\bnotcompared\b).*$
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/nSBZa2/1/)

or this one in `m` mode

```
^(?=[\s\S]*\bacompared\b|\bthiscompared\b|\bnotcompared\b)[\s\S]*$
```

might be a start to solve this problem.

#### [DEMO 3](https://regex101.com/r/AN6EGp/1/)

#### Test 1 with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"^(?=.*\bacompared\b|\bthiscompared\b|\bnotcompared\b).*$"

test_str = ("Net income was $9.4 million acompared to the prior year of $2.7        million.,\n\n"
    "some other words with new lines")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Test 2 with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"^(?=[\s\S]*\bacompared\b|\bthiscompared\b|\bnotcompared\b)[\s\S]*$"

test_str = ("Net income was $9.4 million acompared to the prior year of $2.7        million.,\n\n"
    "some other words with new lines")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this still not working on spaCy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this regex even working with python re because this tries to match  `word followed by compared followed by word (surrounded by word boundaries )` there's nothing in your text which matches the following pattern

```
\b\wcompared\w\b
```

[image]

You can simply change your regex to

```
\b(a|this|not)compared\b
```

[image]

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/MG5IYJ/1/)